# Why CPU registers act like roots for Garbage Collector?

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, memory-fences

Why CPU registers act like roots for Garbage Collector? When a mutator pauses, so the garbage collector can scan the roots, the variables contents are flushed to memory (using a memory fence) so the registers dont contain data that isnt in memory... if my understanding is correct...

Why then do you need to scan them? I see this as redundancy...

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have garbage collection. Are you asking about a particular language extension, or a different language?

Comment: C++ and garbage collection together... while there are garbage collectors for C++ there is no standard one. You will have to make this question more detailed by including what garbage collector you are talking about.

Comment: In my knowledge the roots are the variables in the stack and the global variables in the general context of GC.

Comment: Exactly how cpu register can be a "root" for anything? As far as I know, on assembly level CPU simply doesn't work the way you described. This part in particular doesn't make *any* sense to me *"variables contents are flushed to memory (using a memory fence) so the registers dont contain data that isnt in memory"* Registers are not related to memory, and GC wouldn't operate on register level, plus variables are already in memory so you can't flush them there.

Comment: I am asking this because I want to implement a GC in C++.

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho: I don't see how that's related to CPU registers. Register simply holds value/number that can be used in several ways. CPU doesn't know what this value means. Also, I'm pretty sure there should be several garbage collector libraries for C++. Before writing your own, you might want to investigate existing projects.

Comment: @SigTerm: Maybe I wasnt clear enough... The CPU register may contain intermediate results (including pointers tracked by the GC). Eventually the register value will be written to memory (the exact moment when this happen is defined by the compiler and the way it compiles a section of code). I understand that If I pause a thread that´s not at a safe point, the instruction that writes the register value may not have been executed. I want to know if I put a std::atomic_thread_fence, can I guarantee that all "cached" register values are written to memory and can be seen in the other threads?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho: *"Eventually the register value will be written to memory"* This is not true and is not guaranteed. Variable may be converted into register entirely. It is possible that value will never written to memory. It is possible that address (stored in register) will be reused. It is possible that register value will remain unchanged even after external function call. If you want to write a GC, I'd recommend to operate on higher level than CPU. AFAIK, CPU registers are multi-purpose and do not simply store "intermediate results" of calculation.

Comment: Is there a way in C++ to make sure that a local variable or function parameter will never be stored in register? I want variables to always be baked into memory...

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho There is absolutely no standard way to do this, because the C++ standard doesn't even provide the notion of registers (the `register` keyword is a mere hint, and seldom used at all ; with modern compilers it is probably even ignored anyway because compilers do a better job at this kind of optimization than we could ever do).

Answer (score 0):

The flushing to memory is an implementation detail. The important thing is that the data contained in registers at the time a GC cycle is initiated is treated as reachable, regardless of how or where that data is stored in memory during the GC cycle itself.

Comment: My question is: If I guarantee that all mutators are paused and they (the mutators) have called `std::atomic_thread_fence` before pausing... have all the register values been flushed to memory after `std::atomic_thread_fence`? So, if everything is flushed to memory (and assuming that the programmer won't himself change a register value), why do I need to read the registers when scanning the roots?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho No you cannot guarantee that all registers are flushed to memory, if only because a conformant implementation is allowed to have register-only variables (yes, even pointers to objects) that are never written to memory.

Comment: But if I use the & operator on those variables, then I will force them to not be register only. Right?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho: No, because you cannot predict what compiler will do with the value. You do not know what kind of CPU instructions compiler will produce and how and where it will store variables. Your idea will only work on some kind of custom-tailored compiler (which will be inefficient compared to alternatives). Try different approach.

Comment: I wonder then what address a compiler would return for a variable baked into a register...